# Printing C array on Console

Tags: c, arrays, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here

    char d[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6};

    printf("%s" ,d);
    int i ;
    for(i = 0; i < 6 ; i++)
        printf("%c " , d[i]);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I tried this small snippet on ideone.com. I was not able to get any output on console. Can someone please let me know whats wrong here?

Comment: You're printing the values as `%c`. They are not printable.

Comment: Perfect!. I got my answer. They are not printable!

Answer (score 3):

Replace this:

```
    printf("%c " , d[i]);
```

with

```
    printf("%d " , (int)d[i]);
```

Assuming you want to treat the items in `d` as numbers.

Comment: Thanks Andrea for your help!. Your answer is correct. Also as Daniel kamil Kozar pointed out in the above comment. The values which I am trying to print are not printable!

Comment: @anup.stackoverflow Other answer is change declaration as `char d[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'};` Note `"1"` is a string literal, `'1'` is a char, `1` is an int.

Comment: Thanks Grijesh!. I tried '1'. It takes the ascii value of '1' which is 49. So as expected. Thanks again.

Comment: @anup.stackoverflow If you use `'1'` then One is a char (as I said in above comment) then correct format string would be `%c`. So things are like this `printf(" %s %c %d", "1", '1', 1)`